# Pretty print Python dictionary from command line

Tags: python, dictionary, pretty-print

I can pretty print JSON from the command line easily:

```
$ echo '{"hello": "world"}' |python -mjson.tool
{
    "hello": "world"
}
```

However it doesn't work for Python dictionaries (obviously):

```
$ echo "{'hello': None}" |python -mjson.tool
Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)
```

Is there some built-in class I can use similar to `json.tool` to pretty print Python data structures?

Comment: [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This project is a nice solution to this problem:

https://github.com/wolever/pprintpp

From the README:

```
$ pip install pprintpp

$ echo "{'hello': 'world'}" | pypprint
{'hello': 'world'}
```

Comment: *How* dose this project provide a solution to this 'problem'? Can you at the very least include some examples?

Comment: An SO question isn't an appropriate medium for advertising a third-party library (indeed, the question *"What library can I use to do ..."* is off-topic). If this library *does* solve your problem, please be clear about what the problem was (some specific limitation of `pprint`, perhaps?) and precisely how this library solves it.

Comment: I wasn't advertising, I was taking a note of a solution to my problem (which took me some time to google, next time it will take 5 secs).

Answer (score 6):

If you really wanted a command-line solution, you could use the [`pprint` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) in a command line:

```
$ echo "{'python': {'hello': [1,2,3,4,42,81,113,256], 'world': ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs', 'bacon', 'eric', 'idle']}}" \
    | python -c 'import sys; from pprint import pprint as pp; pp(eval(sys.stdin.read()))'
{'python': {'hello': [1, 2, 3, 4, 42, 81, 113, 256],
            'world': ['spam', 'ham', 'eggs', 'bacon', 'eric', 'idle']}}
```

This is easily be wrapped in a module; name this `pprint_tool.py`:

```
import sys
import ast
from pprint import pprint


def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        infile = sys.stdin
        outfile = sys.stdout
    elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
        infile = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
        outfile = sys.stdout
    elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
        infile = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
        outfile = open(sys.argv[2], 'wb')
    else:
        raise SystemExit(sys.argv[0] + " [infile [outfile]]")
    with infile:
        try:
            obj = ast.literal_eval(infile.read())
        except ValueError as e:
            raise SystemExit(e)
    with outfile:
        pprint(obj, outfile)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This'll work exactly like the `json.tool` module:

```
echo "..." | python -m pprint_tool
```

Comment: Why is this not accessible in Python just like -mjson.tool? This is something I would want to use for every project, just like the json printer.

Comment: @GaborKulcsar: I just open up a Python prompt usually. I don't use this all that often myself. Feel free to make this a [feature request](http://bugs.python.org/).

Comment: @GaborKulcsar JSON is a widely used serialization format, so there's lots of opportunity for pretty printing it.  But how often do people have Python output to format?

Comment: I guess it makes sense if you have Python processes communicating with each other. And it might be that you don't have access to the processes themselves, but the messages are written to a log. And you may have been assigned to this project recently, so you are not familiar with Python at all...

Comment: +1 for `ast.literal_eval`, without which the evals are rather unsafe. JSON already has such a restriction, and implementations in many languages, both good reasons to use it for communication. Python processes frequently communicate using Pickle rather than expressions.